# How to convert NoneType nltk.collocations() into a list or string in Pyhton?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, nonetype

I have problems trying to iterate over a object created with `nltk.collocations()` by doing this
`nltk.Text(word_tokenize(''.join(script))).collocations()`. I get an output like this, which is fine:

> - continuing readingletter; paler skins; machine gun; ARVN soldier; never want; looking around; run back; turns back; n't even; n't know;
>   n't get; n't see; could n't; n't going

The problem is that I can not convert this output into a list or a string because it says is a `NoneType` object. I want to transform this into a string for being able to split it over the " ; " and create a list out of it.

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the value of the input parameter `script`? Provide a complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: @sophros it is a list of strings that contains every line of a movie script. Anyways, the input is not the problem, the problem is that he ouput is always a NoneType object, with the structure that I provide in the resume of the problem. And I want to manipulate this output such as making a list or transforming it to a string

Comment: @coke979 did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @ricgrego no, I have not